# Problems with media query testing and device view

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I wonder if anyone can help me. I'm using http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/ to test the responsive side of this website I'm doing. However, when I test the iPhone 5 it looks ok on the tester but when I check on the actually device the design is all over the place. Does anyone know why this problem has arisen and knows how to fix it.

Thanks all

Comment: Could it be you're possibly not using the right webkits, enabling it to look fine on your browser version, but not iPhone browser.

Comment: While every effort is made for these testers to mimic the actions of the device, their isn't always a guarantee that their behaviour will directly replicate the actual device, so always bare that in mind. And as previously stated by @BeatAlex you have to ensure you're using the right webkits for the device and seeing as their are so many nowadays it can be a little crazy.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many mobile emulators available. One of the best is keynote MITE. Download and try, its free

http://mite.keynote.com/

Comment: Thanks for the download. It's my media queries that need work.

Comment: can you share the code or share the link for us to have look @ it